# Combines table filters in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have a table with different places, and implemented some simple buttons that allow you to filter the list. First filter is location (north, east, central, south, west) which is based on postcode. Another filter is on "impress". This shows you only the places that have have 4 or higher value in the column. Filters work great separately, but not together. The result that I am after is when I press "West" is shows me the places in "West, when I then click impress, I expect to see the places in west with a 4 or 5 score for impress.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gkba343L/)

```js
$('.table td.postcode').each(function() {
 var cellText = $(this).html();
 var locationString = cellText.substring(0,2);
 if (locationString.indexOf('W') > -1){
  $(this).parent().addClass('west');       
 }
 if (locationString.indexOf('C') > -1){
  $(this).parent().addClass('central');       
 } 
 if (locationString.indexOf('E') > -1){
  $(this).parent().addClass('east');       
 }
 if (locationString.indexOf('S') > -1){
  $(this).parent().addClass('south');       
 }
 if (locationString.indexOf('N') > -1){
  $(this).parent().addClass('north');       
 }
});

$("input[name='filterStatus'], select.filter").change(function () {
 var classes = [];

 $("input[name='filterStatus']").each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   classes.push('.'+$(this).val());
  }
 });

 if (classes == "") {
 // if no filters selected, show all items
  $("#StatusTable tbody tr").show();
 } else {
 // otherwise, hide everything...
  $("#StatusTable tbody tr").hide();
                
  // then show only the matching items
  rows = $("#StatusTable tr").filter(classes.length ? classes.join(',') : '*');

  if (rows.size() > 0) {
      rows.show();
  }
 }
            
});

$("input[name='impressStatus']").change(function(){
 var classes = [];

 $("input[name='impressStatus']").each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   classes.push('.'+$(this).val());
  }
 });

 if(classes == ""){
  $("#StatusTable tbody tr").show();
 }

 else{

 $(".table td.impress").each(function(){

   if($(this).data("impress") >= 4){
    $(this).parent().show();
   }
   else{
    $(this).parent().hide();
   }
  }); 
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--BUTTON FILTERS -->
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
    <div class="btn-group" style="" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary outline">
   <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="north" autocomplete="off">North
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary outline">
   <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="east" autocomplete="off" class="radio">East
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary outline">
   <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="central" autocomplete="off" class="radio">Central
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary outline">
   <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="south"autocomplete="off" class="radio">South                </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary outline">
   <input type="checkbox" name="filterStatus" value="west" autocomplete="off" class="radio">West
  </label>
 </div><!-- button group -->
            
 <label class="btn btn-primary outline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="impressStatus" class="radio" aria-pressed="true" autocomplete="off">Impress her
    </label>
 </div><!-- btn toolbar-->
            
 <!--TABLE -->
            
<table class="table" id="StatusTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-sort="string" style="cursor:pointer">name</th>
      <!-- <th>Description</th> -->
          <th data-sort="string" style="cursor:pointer;">postcode</th>
          <th data-sort="int" style="cursor:pointer;">price</th>
          <th data-sort="int" style="cursor:pointer;">total</th>
          <th data-sort="int" style="cursor:pointer;">impress</th>
          <th colspan="4"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr data-link="/places/1">
        <td>Name of place 1</td>
        <td class="postcode">NW1</td>
        <td class="price" data-price='3'>3</td>
        <td class="rating" data-rating='69'>69</td>
        <td class="impress" data-impress='4'>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-link="/places/2">
        <td>Name of place 2</td>
        <td class="postcode">E3</td>
        <td class="price" data-price='4'>4</span></td>
        <td class="rating" data-rating='89'>89</td>
        <td class="impress" data-impress='5'>5</td>
      
      </tr>
      <tr data-link="/places/3">
        <td>Name of place 3</td>
        <td class="postcode">SW3</td>
        <td class="price" data-price='2'>2</td>
        <td class="rating" data-rating='51'>51</td>
        <td class="impress" data-impress='3'>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Code is probably not the most efficient, but it works :). Once I got this working, I want to add more filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(sorry for my bad english)*

if these are the only filters you need, you can use two different type of filter:

1. hide via Javascript
2. hide via Css

if you use 2 types of filters the filters can work correctly without use a complex javascript code to manage a big number of different cases and combination:

I add a initial (on document load) control that check if a `tr` has the value `impress` cell >4, if has it add a new class: `is_impress` else add an other: `no_impress`.

```
$('.table td.impress').each(function(){
    var _class = ($(this).data("impress") >= 4) ? "is_impress" : "no_impress";
    $(this).parent().addClass(_class);
});
```

The code of filter by position is the same... but... I edit the filter by `impress` to add a class to `table` () when is active and take it off when isn't:

```
$("input[name='impressStatus']").change(function(){
    (!$(this).is(":checked"))
        ? $("#StatusTable").removeClass("active_impress")
        : $("#StatusTable").addClass("active_impress");
});
```

if the table has the class `active_impress` a css rules override the inline code of `dispaly` to hide all the row that haven't an impress >4:

```
#StatusTable.active_impress tr.no_impress{
    display:none !important;
}
```

This type of filter override any other display modification until the checkbox stay checked.

I edit your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/gkba343L/1/

### USE CSS to more filter

First change on load check, add `price`:

```
$('.table tbody tr').each(function(){
    var _class = "";
    _class += ($(this).find(".price").data("price") >= 2) ? "is_price " : "no_price ";
    _class += ($(this).find(".impress").data("impress") >= 4) ? "is_impress " : "no_impress ";
    console.log(_class);
    $(this).addClass(_class);
});
```

Add an other handler to new filter:

```
$("input[name='priceStatus']").change(function(){
    (!$(this).is(":checked"))
        ? $("#StatusTable").removeClass("active_price")
        : $("#StatusTable").addClass("active_price");
});
```

add new selector to the css rule:

```
#StatusTable.active_impress tr.no_impress,
#StatusTable.active_price tr.no_price{
    display:none !important;
}
```

This is the result:
https://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/gkba343L/3/

### Optimize code to add more filter:

HTML filter button:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary outline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="impress" class="cssFilter radio" aria-pressed="true" autocomplete="off">Impress her
</label>
```

use `cssFilter` to indicate that is a css filter button and use `name` attribute to define the name of the filter, than use this namespace into the css class:

`.active_{name}` `.no_{name}` `.is_{name}`

And use a generic handler:

```
$("input.cssFilter").change(function(){
    var _name = $(this).attr("name");
    console.log(_name);
    (!$(this).is(":checked"))
        ? $("#StatusTable").removeClass("active_"+_name)
        : $("#StatusTable").addClass("active_"+_name);
});
```

With this you can manage all the filter with an unique handler, remember to add the filter to onload check and the new selector for each new filter.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/gkba343L/4/

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to add more filters in the near future. For example one that only shows cheaper places (price >=2)

Comment: You can add all the filter you need (the same type as impress) i edit my answer to show you how...